# Confusion with obtaining a value from a JSON string using GSON

Tags: java, json, gson

so I've had the idea to try and make a program which can obtain subscriber counts through Google APIs, however my lack of knowledge in JSON has become my downfall.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    String url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels? 
    part=statistics&key=sWDdmcweForstackoverflowDW&forUsername=damonandjo";
    URL obj = new URL(url);

    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0");

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
    InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

This will print information such as this to the console.
https://pastebin.com/jqTCJTtR

My question is how would I go about parsing this, and what is the easiest way to do it with it out running it through other classes etc? I have tried multiple different libraries and a lot seem to be outwith the bounds of what I am trying to achieve. Thank you very much to anyone willing to help.

EDIT: So with the help of Not a JD I have been able to make some progress with this, however I believe the map is iterating over the actual arrays and not their contents which is what I want to access. If anyone can help me do this Ibwould be very grateful

Comment: Using `Gson` you can deserialise `JSON` to `Map` or create `POJO` model and deserialise it to `POJO`. Which one do you prefer? @NotaJD suggested to deserialise it to `Map`. Does it work for you?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what a POJO model is, I'm not too familiar with JSON in java. Deserialising it in to the map lets me view the objects in the JSON file, but doesn't let me access the strings ETC inside of them which is what I want to do.

Comment: The only thing I need to do is get the actual value of the string "subscriberCount" in the JSON file. I managed to do this with java-json but I would rather use GSON due to the environment I'm trying to run it in.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and easy might be to use gson:

```
    Gson gson = new Gson(); 
    Map<String,Object> map = (Map<String,Object>) gson.fromJson(jsonString, Map.class);
```

Take a look at the keys in the map.

E.g. `map.get(resultsPerPage)` will return 5.

Comment: Thank you for this, so if I wished to print it to the console it would look like this?
System.out.println(map.get("resultsPerPage"));

Comment: For some reason, when passing "resultsPerPage" through map.get(), it is returning null?

Comment: Try dumping all the keys - System.out.println(map.keySet()) - what does it return?

Comment: Returns as "null"
Edit: no it doesn't, i'm a fool. returns
[kind, etag, pageInfo, items]

Comment: So I can do System.out.println(map.get(items)), which will return me all of the items in the items array (?), not sure how to access individual values within it though.

Comment: System.out.println(map.get("items").getClass().getName()) then case map.get("items") to that. It looks like it might be a List<Map>.

Answer (score 0):

You can always deserialise every `JSON` to `Map` of key value pairs or `List` of `Map`-s. It depends from your root object in `JSON`. In your case you have `JSON object` so we can deserialise it to `Map`. Knowing that we can deserialise given `JSON` and find `subscriberCount` as below:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Optional;

public class GsonApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();
        FileReader json = new FileReader(jsonFile);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

        Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {
        }.getType();
        Map<String, Object> response = gson.fromJson(json, type);

        Optional<Integer> subscriberCount = getSubscriberCount(response);
        if (subscriberCount.isPresent()) {
            System.out.println(subscriberCount.get());
        }
    }

    public static Optional<Integer> getSubscriberCount(Map<String, Object> response) {
        Object items = response.get("items");
        if (items instanceof List) {
            Object item0 = ((List) items).get(0);
            if (item0 instanceof Map) {
                Object statistics = ((Map) item0).get("statistics");
                if (statistics instanceof Map) {
                    Object subscriberCount = ((Map) statistics).get("subscriberCount");
                    return Optional.of(Integer.parseInt(subscriberCount.toString()));
                }
            }
        }

        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
```

In case your `items` element can more element you need to iterate over it. Also check whether `items` is not empty. Example shows hot to get `0-element` from it.